# Lumen - I'm getting CORS error when trying POST request with some header, but without header everything is ok

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, lumen

So my problem is: I Have Lumen server on subdomain **api.domain.com**
After sending ajax request from ***domain.com*** to ***api.domain.com***:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.domain.com/login',
            type: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'someJWTTOKEN'
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log('result');
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

Now I get CORS error:
[image]

**But when I remove Header from ajax request, everything works fine.**

This works great:

```
   $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.domain.com/login',
                type: 'post',
                headers: {
                },
                data: {},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log('result');
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Without the `Authorization` header, this does not require a pre-flight request, but with it, it does. The error message says there was no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response, so it seems your system is not set up to handle pre-flight requests correctly.

Comment: add cors middleware

Comment: I created Cors middleware but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem connecting my React app to my Lumen API but solved it by using this [PHP Package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors#lumen). In the README they explain how to configure the package with Lumen. Legit took me like 2 minutes.